# Set maxLength attribute on ComboBox

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to add a maxLength to the custom value on the ComboBox but when I do

```
getElement().setAttribute("maxLength","30");
```

Vaadin add it to the wrapping vaadin-combo-box element. How can I access from Java the underlying highlighted  input element as show in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can executejs on client side through element API. I solved using this snippet:

```
element.executeJs("this.childNodes.item(0).maxLength = 30")
```

"childNodes.item(0)" is the underlying input element of combobox

Answer (score 0):

Applying a max-length on the client-side does not guarantee that the value on the server-side is secured.

Instead of mingling with the inner workings of the ComboBox's field, I would suggest to apply this validation on the server-side. In the `ComboBox::addCustomValueSetListener` or by using a `StringLengthValidator` on the `Binder` you have attached to the form/field.

Comment: I'm using addCustomValueSetListener too server side, but that fire only when user blur or press enter. I'd like the user could not digit more than 30 chars before bluring out or pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin ComboBox doesn't support setting a max length to custom values (although TextField does).

You could create a feature request ticket about it here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature-request.yml